# Creating a var in javascript; modification of a script to create var usage?

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly simple problem for someone familiar with js.  I quite like the style of the audio player from: http://wpaudio.com/

I've taken this and have it mostly extracted to a rails project, however it turns out that the  WordPress plugin creates a variable `_wpaudio` within php as follows:

```
## WPaudio style, jQuery, SWFObject
function wpaHead(){
    global $wpa_options;
    # Put all styles into the _wpaudio settings object
    $style = '';
    foreach ( $wpa_options as $key => $value ) {
        $exploded = explode('_', $key, 3);
        if ( $exploded[1] == 'style' ) {
            $style .= $exploded[2] . ":'$value',";
        }
    }
    $style = trim( $style, ',' );
    $style = '{' . $style . '}';
    # Common JS
    $wpa_pref_link_mp3 = ($wpa_options['wpa_pref_link_mp3']) ? 'true' : 'false';
    $head = "<script type='text/javascript'>/* <![CDATA[ */ var _wpaudio = {url: '" . WPAUDIO_URL . "', enc: {}, convert_mp3_links: $wpa_pref_link_mp3, style: $style}; /* ]]> */</script>";
    echo $head;
}
```

**Obviously nearly ALL of that code is not pertinent**, however it's simply to illustrate that the `_wpaudio` var is created there.  I don't really care to have the paths built, etc.  I simply want to be able to manipulate the script such that the var is created within the js file.  I've tried a few different ways, but I'm so uninitiated in javascript that my attempts have been futile thus far.

Here's the javascript which fails on load in the console with the `Can't find variable: _wpaudio` error: 
https://gist.github.com/fd208d327484306d65a9

**How do I modify the script so that it properly creates the _wpaudio at initialization?**

Comment: I've looked through your error case.  But I don't see where you're ever instantiating an object called _wpaudio.  Are you missing some code?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, that's exactly what I need to do here initially.  I'm not exactly sure where to instantiate the object in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a search for _wpaudio across the files of the wpaudio plugin folder, you will find this, at line 150 of wpaudio.php (yup, the one that appears in the snippet you provide):

```
$head = "<script type='text/javascript'>/* <![CDATA[ */ var _wpaudio = {url: "[[path/to/wpaudio-mp3-player]]", enc: {}, convert_mp3_links: [[true|false]], style: {[[style]]} }; /* ]]> */</script>";
```

This tells you that you are supposed to insert this script snippet somewhere in your html page. The $head means that the plugin will add it in the head part of the document (<head>...</head>). That could be as good a place as any. In any case, a _wpaudio variable should exist before the plugin is initialized, that script snippet should be inserted before you load wpaudio.js.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
  var _wpaudio = {
   url: "[[path/to/wpaudio-mp3-player]]", 
   enc: {}, 
   convert_mp3_links: [[true|false]], 
   style: {[[style formatting as a json object, empty object should work]]} }; 
 /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Alright, this is very helpful, thanks.  I did it a touch differently, however it's getting initialized now.  I am, however, having a problem and am curious if you'd be able to advise.  I'm getting: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href$=.mp3]`.  In the initialization function I see this (line 10): http://j.mp/ywsCrl

Comment: Got it, never mind.  The .mp3 was simply not quoted.  Works great and looks great!  WPAudio is now a super implementation of a link based audio player for Rails now!